# Merge the tag [sql-operations-studio] into [azure-data-studio]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [sql-operations-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-operations-studio) appears to have lingered. SQL Operations Studio was the initial name for Azure Data Studio, but on full release Microsoft changed the name (why it has Azure in the name is beyond me, but that's a different problem). Can we merge [sql-operations-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-operations-studio) into [azure-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-studio)? The description for the tag even says it's "deprecated". Though it doesn't look like there's any new questions for it, they should still be cleaned up.

Comment: Have you gotten approval for this naming change from the Microsoft Windows Azure Official Product Naming Committee™?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @CodyGray . Microsoft changed the name *years* ago...

Comment: J̵u̵s̵t̵ ̵f̵a̵i̵l̵e̵d̵ ̵h̵u̵m̵o̵u̵r̵.̵ What is the committee's new name?

Comment: Probably something like "Office 365 PowerBI Azure Platform Products Naming Committee" now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [sql-operations-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-operations-studio) tag was removed from 12 questions and the [azure-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-studio) tag was added to 13 questions (18 total questions affected). 5 favorite/ignored tags were remapped.

I've chosen to retain the [sql-operations-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-operations-studio) tag as a synonym of [azure-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-studio). Otherwise, this was just a straightforward tag rename/merge.